# Arrays in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3

I am trying to convert a project to Swift 3. However I am stuck converting an array declaration:

> Cannot convert value of type [Task<>] to specified type [Task]

```
var tasks: [Task] = [] as! [Task]
```

Task is declared like so in Objective-C (part of a library):

```
@class Task;

@interface Task<__covariant ResultType> : NSObject
```

I'm not sure what's going on?

Comment: Please show what your `Task` is.

Comment: hello @OOPer I have added that information - thank you.

Comment: In a declaration line a declared non-optional type casted forced unwrapped  to the same type is pretty silly, no offense.

Comment: ObjC generics are imported as Swift generics in Swift 3. And you always need to specify the type parameter of the generic class, like `var tasks: [Task<SomeSpecificType>] = []`. (Ignore "silly" suggestion from Xcode.) If you cannot choose one specific type for that parameter, there may not be a quick fix and need to show more context.

Comment: Why are you doing `var tasks: [Task] = [] as! [Task]` and not `var tasks: [Task] = []`?

Comment: @WMios because you get "Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to specified type '[Task]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume at first you tried to write

```
var tasks: [Task] = []
```

and the compiler told you:

```
cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to specified type '[Task]'
var tasks: [Task] = []
                    ^~
                       as! [Task]
```

What's actually going on here is that the compiler is trying to infer the generic parameter of the generic type `Task`, and failing. You can't have an array of unspecified `Task` instances.

You must either make an array of concrete `Task` instances:

```
var tasks: [Task<ConcreteResultType>] = []
```

or you must make a generic array of Tasks

```
var tasks: [Task<T>] = []
```

where `T` is declared in the encompassing scope.

Comment: Thank you Alexander,  It's sad that Swift 3 requires a break down of the components in such a way but I believe your answer goes in line with  OOPer's answer as well .

Comment: What do you mean? What do you expect Swift to do?

Comment: The library in use it's in Objective - C. There was no problem using it in Swift 2.2, but Swift 3 has made things a bit more complicated.

Comment: `a break down of the components in such a way` What does that mean?

Comment: What I mean is in Swift 2.2 I could do this ->   var tasks: [Task] = [] 
where Task is @ class Task; and  @interface Task<__covariant ResultType> : NSObject as declared in the objective C library

Comment: That's a crucial flaw, Swift 2.2 didn't import the generics of Objc classes.